# странный путь ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route

Написал простенький роутинг на ангуляре, но путь имеет странный вид, например:
http://127.0.0.1:61257/index.html#!#%2Fnew
вместо ожидаемого http://127.0.0.1:61257/index.html#/new

В чем может быть проблема?

JS:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/new", {
        template: "<h1> Новые </h1>"
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
 <nav>
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#/new">Новые</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/underway">В работе</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/inProcessing">На рассмотрении</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/done">Выполнены</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/decline">Отменены</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/draft">Черновики</a></li>
                    <hr>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Скрипты подключаю в `head` в таком порядке:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/routers.js"></script>
```

Comment: в ангуларе не шарю, но первый запрос в гугл дал ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272314/angular-all-slashes-in-url-changed-to-2f , посмотрите, може что вам поможет

Comment: в Angular 1.6 они поменяли `#` на `#!`

Comment: помогло, спасибо

Comment: оформите как ответ, кто-то из вас

Comment: используйте `@uirouter/angularjs`. Больше возможностей, сами разработчики ангуляра советуют